# How to get the explicit formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the explicit formula for $A_{n+1} = 0.90 \space A_n$ where $A(5) = 1000$? I have no idea how to find the solution to this.

Comment: Try writing the terms $A_5$, $A_6$, $A_7$, $\ldots$ down (don't simplify at first)...

Answer (score 2):

Each time $n$ increases, you multiply by $0.9$  So $A_n=1000\cdot 0.9^{n-5}$  You could change this to an exponent of $n$ if you want by changing the $1000$.  Can you solve that?

Answer (score 1):

$$A_{n}=0.9A_{n-1}=0.9^{2}A_{n-2}=\cdots=0.9^{n-5}A_{5}=0.9^{n-5}\cdot1000$$